# how to set dismiss time of dialog box when using in try and catch exception?

Tags: android

i want to set dismiss time for this dialog box,, i want to dismiss this "Saved" dialog after 2 second but don't know how ,i am a beginner in android..help me and thanks in advance

```
try{
}catch(Exception e){
diditwork = false;  
}finally{
if (diditwork){
Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setTitle("Saved");
d.show();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should just use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) instead? It seems appropriate for the task, and will automatically dismiss itself.

Comment: Definitely a case for a Toast.  But if you did need to do something like this, you'd want to store the dialog reference in a class scope variable, and use a delayed message on a Handler to hide it.

Comment: Hey thanks By using toast now i can set dismiss time..

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but for anyone reading this, if you want to use a Dialog, you can dismiss it after a period of time by using the Timer class:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //put code to execute here:
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);
```